# Unable to use dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:) from a xib file

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am having trouble casting my table view cell to my custom table view cell in the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:)` step.

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldcell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell
    cell.labelTitle.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

I have registered my cell in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.register(TextFieldTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldcell")
```

And I got an error saying:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I bet it failed the casting and that is why the cell is empty. Can anybody see the error?

Thanks!

**UPDATED CODE**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let bundle = Bundle(for: TextFieldTableViewCell.self)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldcell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldcell", for: indexPath) as! TextFieldTableViewCell
        cell.labelTitle.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

So apparently the issue still persists, to clarify, here are the steps I took to create this custom UITableViewCell

1. Create a .swift file and a .xib file
2. inside of the .xib file, I have deleted the boilerplate code and added in two UILabels
3. I set the file owner of the .xib file to my swift, which has my two IBOutlets
4. Next, inside of my tableViewController where I want to instantiate my custom tableViewCell, inside the `viewDidLoad()` method, I added in the following:

`let bundle = Bundle(for: TextFieldTableViewCell.self)`

`let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: bundle)`

`tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldcell")`

My reasoning for creating this code are as follow: since I have create my custom table view cell using a .xib file and interface builder, I need to load the xib into my tableViewController (correct me if I am wrong) using `tableView.register(nibName: forCellReuseIdentifier:)` function.

However, when I run the code, I got an error saying: `reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle`

Here is my code for my custom cell:

```
class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userInput: UITextField!
}
```

Can anybody see where the problem is? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to register your nib object.

In viewDidLoad():

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "nameOfYourNibFile", bundle: nil)

tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "yourIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `UITableViewCell` subclass is designed in Interface Builder you should use the

```
func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

method. For example:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(TextFieldTableViewCell.self)", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldcell")
```

If your `UITableViewCell` subclass is created entirely in code you should use the

```
func register(_ cellClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

method.

If you're using prototype cells in a storyboard you should not register your cells at all.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have created my cell in a xib file and I have registered my cell, but somehow it fails

Comment: In your question you say you are using `func register(_ cellClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) `. But if you used an xib you should be using `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`. If that's not the case, perhaps you can update your question to more accurately reflect what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!!appreciate your help!

Comment: sorry, actually the error still persists, I have updated my code above, can you please check? thanks! many help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer. I should have been more specific. You should say something like `let nib = UINib(nibName: "\(TextFieldTableViewCell.self)", bundle: nil); tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TextFieldcell")`. I was using `MyTableViewCell` as an example of a `UITableViewCell` subclass name. Typically when you create an xib in Xcode it will have the same name as the class you are creating in your case `TextFieldTableViewCell`. We can pass `nil` in for the bundle because we want to use the default main bundle of the app.

Comment: Thanks for you input!